# How to programmatically delete network connection?

Tags: c#, .net

How can I delete active network connection to shared resource programmatically instead of `net use \\machinename /delete` ?

Comment: `Process.Start("net use \\machinename /delete")`

Comment: If you don't want to spawn out to CMD, you might have to pinvoke `WNetCancelConnection2` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385427(v=vs.85).aspx